# Example expectation of an exponential function

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, geometric-topology

Given a geometric random variable $Y$ with $p = 1/3$, I know that $E[Y] = 1/p = 3$.

However, what is $E[e^{aY}]$ ? for a small value $a$.

Thanks

Comment: Define geometric random variable.

Comment: A variable that follows the geometric distribution. So $P(Y=1)=1/3$, $P(Y=2)=1/9$, $P(Y=3)=1/27$ and so on.

Comment: @johnny: It is $\Pr(Y=1)=1/3$, $\Pr(Y=2)=(2/3)(1/3)$, $\Pr(Y=3)=(2/3)^2(1/3)$ and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @AndréNicolas!

Comment: You are welcome. It is the probability that the first success occurs at the $k$-th trial in a sequence of  independent trials, where the probability of success on any trial is $1/3$, and therefore the probability of failure is $2/3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k$ is a positive integer, then the random variable $X$ takes on the value $k$ with probability $p(1-p)^{k-1}$. It follows by the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) that
$$E(e^{aY})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{ak} p(1-p)^{k-1}.$$
This is an infinite geometric series with first term equal to $pe^a$ and common ratio $r=(1-p)e^a$.  If $r\lt 1$, the series converges. For a simplified version of the value, use the ordinary formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series.